# expected conv2d input to have shape (5665,445,3) but got aray with shape (1,445,3)

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, convolution

I have data of input shape (5665,445,3) but when I run my code I got this error `expected conv2d input to have shape (5665,445,3) but got aaray with shape (1,445,3)` I don't why. Any I idea why I get this error and how to solve it ??

**code**:

```
def generate_arrays_for_training(indexPat, paths, start=0, end=100):     
    while True:
        from_=int(len(paths)/100*start)
        to_=int(len(paths)/100*end)
        for i in range(from_, int(to_)):
            f=paths[i]
            x = np.load(PathSpectogramFolder+f)
            x=x[:,:,:-1] #3channels
            x=np.array([x])
            x=x.swapaxes(0,1)
            if('P' in f):
                y = np.repeat([[0,1]],x.shape[0], axis=0)
            else:
                y =np.repeat([[1,0]],x.shape[0], axis=0)
            yield(x,y)
def createModel():
    input_shape=(5665, 445, 3)
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(16, ( 5, 5), strides=( 2, 2), padding='same',activation='relu',data_format= "channels_last", input_shape=input_shape))
    model.add(keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=( 2, 2),data_format= "channels_last",  padding='same'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Conv2D(32, ( 3, 3), strides=( 1,1), padding='same',data_format= "channels_last",  activation='relu'))
    model.add(keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2),data_format= "channels_last",padding='same' ))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), strides=(1,1), padding='same',data_format= "channels_last",  activation='relu'))
    model.add(keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2),data_format= "channels_last",padding='same' ))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(256, activation='sigmoid'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
return model
```

Comment: It is your data processing problem. Check your input data shape.

Comment: @ashraful How it can be a processing problem?? what do you mean ??

Comment: while training you are giving images (1,445,3) shape

Answer (score 0):

## Why the error array with shape (1,445,3)

After inspecting your code, I've identified that your function `generate_arrays_for_training` will return a shape of `x.shape is (5665, 1, 445, 3)`.  This looks like it happens from the line `x=x.swapaxes(0,1)`, which swaps the space of the first and second dimension.

Commenting out that line returns a better response of `x.shape is (1, 5665, 445, 3)`

## Working code

I've rewritten and simplified your generator along, and am supplying the supporting code that tests it

```
import numpy as np

def make_training():
    for i in range(10):
        name = f'data/item{i}'
        np.save(name, np.zeros([5665,445,4]))
        yield name+'.npy'

paths = [ _ for _ in make_training() ]
PathSpectogramFolder ='./'

def generate_arrays_for_training(paths):     
    while True:
        for path in paths:
            x = np.load(PathSpectogramFolder+path)
            x=x[:,:,:-1] #3channels
            x=np.array([x])
            if('P' in path):
                y = np.repeat([[0,1]],x.shape[0], axis=0)
            else:
                y = np.repeat([[1,0]],x.shape[0], axis=0)
            yield(x,y)

gen = generate_arrays_for_training(paths)
x,y = next(gen)
print('x.shape is',x.shape)
print('y.shape is',y.shape)
```

The output is so:

```
x.shape is (1, 5665, 445, 3)
y.shape is (1, 2)
```